# how to write Rails model query between date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is my sql query I wont to convert into rails model query

```
sql : SELECT "vouchers".* FROM "vouchers" WHERE "vouchers"."business_id" = 31 AND '2014-08-20'  between start_date and end_date;
```

My tried model query but this not working please help me to make it working

```
Voucher.where(["#{Date.today} BETWEEN ? AND ?",:start_date,:end_date])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that start_date and end_date are columns try this version

```
Voucher.where("current_date between start_date and end_date").where(business_id: 31)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try in this format:

```
data = ModelName.where("today >= from_date AND today <= to_date")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.where("DATE(created_at) > :today AND DATE(promoted_till_date) < :two_weeks", today: Date.today, two_weeks: Date.today+14.days)
```